# google fusion table query for string that contains pound sign (#)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I am having trouble getting google fusion table API (using google app script) to query strings that contain a #.

In all the following examples, I set a string variable called sql and then call it with:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql='+sql ,getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText();
```

The following fails:

```
var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name = 'MT TAM - Y #'"
```

Using a wildcard succeeds:
    var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name LIKE 'MT TAM - Y _'"

but fails when I try to do the same thing using an IN statement (which is what I'd really like to do).  For example, the following fails:

```
var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name IN('MT TAM - Y _','MT TAM - R _','MT TAM - G _')"
```

I have tried surrounding the string with back qutoes as well as using a backslash before the hash and even putting the hash mark inside square brackets.  All of the following have failed:

```
var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name = `MT TAM - Y #`"
var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name = ``MT TAM - Y #``"
var sql = "SELECT ROWID,name from " +ITEMTABLE_KEY  +" WHERE name = 'MT TAM - Y [#]'"
```

Unfortunately the project I'm working on already has 700 items in another db which does not make unique ID #'s available in its reports. I'd like the users to run reports out of that db and use the identifiers in the report to key off of for this project.  And more than half of those identifiers contain # because in our db it denotes things sold by the pound.  Any way to get the fusion table API query statements to accept a #?

Comment: how do you run the query?

Comment: I have a function which takes the string variable I call 'sql' and processes it with the following command:  `UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql='+sql ,getUrlFetchOptions()).getContentText();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the FusionTablesService to send  the query:

```
var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet("SELECT ROWID,name FROM " +
                                        ITEMTABLE_KEY +" 
                                        WHERE name = 'MT TAM - Y #'");
```

Related:

- [how to enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [how to use the Fusion Tables Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables)

Comment: Thank you so much.  That worked! I am a little confused still as to the differences between using the UrlFetchApp service and the Query method of the FusionTables service.  But this definitely worked!  Thanks.

Comment: The difference will be the encoding, I guess UrlFetchApp doesn't encode the `#` so it will not be a part of `sql` , it defines an anchor for the URL instead